# Find items with matching string from a List

Tags: java

I have a Java class:

```
class GlobalUsers {

   String name = ""
   String ID = ""
   ................
   ................
}
```

Now in another function:

```
List<GlobalUsers> guObjs = new List<GlobalUsers>();
```

Here i have few hundreds of objects of GlobalUsers in a List.

I want to find all objects of GlobalUsers where string `name == "User_CUSTOM"`

So basically the result will be another List:

```
List<GlobalUsers> guObjs = *name == "User_CUSTOM"*
```

How can i do this the easiest way?

Comment: Have you implemented `equals` for `GlobalUsers`?

Comment: No. I am new to Java, so don't have much idea about that.

Comment: Okay, so you need to read up on equality of objects in Java; then read the use of the `Comparator` interface; then you look at sorting collections, so you can use the binary search function in the `Collections` class

Comment: @kolossus it is not sorting issue it is finding matches issue, comparable has nothing to do with it. Also sorting is O(NlogN) while finding matches is O(N).

Comment: The collection needs to be sorted, if the [binary search is to be of any use](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T)) @Zielu

Comment: @kolossus , binary search is of no use here, as he needs to all the matching elements not one. Choose the right tool for the job.

Comment: What version of Java are you running @Kris

Answer (score 4):

Use the Streams API:

```
   guObjs.stream().filter(u -> "User_CUSTOM".equals(u.name)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Filter does exactly what you wanted, gets a function that check if the input value is ok or not (in your case if the name matches the requested "User_CUSTOM" value. Collect takes all the matching results and places them back in a list.